# Jquery drop down menu - not working

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm working on this jQuery drop down menu and the code is not working. I think it may have something to do with the css property .dropdown ul {display:none }

I'm not very good with jQuery (yet)...Any suggestions?

http://codepen.io/ElaineM/pen/Jokxb

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which dropdown library you're using, but it seems that your HTML is wrong.

You have:

```
<li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Try this instead:

```
<li>
  <a href="#">Item 1  
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks! It makes sense that you would wrap the nested/second <ul> inside of the main <li> tag.

Comment: Remember that that **only** valid direct child element in `<ul>` is `<li>` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qtaLi
Is it what you wanted? 
Your HTML should be like

```
 <li><a href="#">Item 1</a> 
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
     </ul>
</li>
```

And CSS:

```
.dropdown li:hover > ul{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks, I didn't realize I needed to wrap the second <ul> tag inside of the main <li> tag. Also, using  a child selector in the CSS is a good suggestion.